# C++: Is it safe to compare a 64bit integer with a 32bit integer?

Tags: c++

Assuming I have 2 variables:

```
uint64_t a = ...

uint32_t b = ...
```

Will comparing the integers yield the expected results, i.e. `(a != b)`, or `(b > a)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770258/how-do-promotion-rules-work-when-the-signedness-on-either-side-of-a-binary-opera

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No problem. The compiler promotes the 32-bit to 64-bit before the comparison

Comment: Search for C++ integer promotion rules for more info.

Comment: Yes, but if one is signed and the other is unsigned, then the comparison may not work.

Comment: The question started "Assume I have .. uint64_t ... uint32_t". If we assume that, then neither is signed.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer - yes. The 'smaller' is converted to bigger one before comparison.