# C++ Integer Overflow and Promotion

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do promotion rules work when the signedness on either side of a binary operator differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770258/how-do-promotion-rules-work-when-the-signedness-on-either-side-of-a-binary-opera)

I'm trying to wrap my head around integer promotion and overflow in C++. I'm a bit confused with several points:

**a)** If I have the following code segment:

```
int i = -15; 
unsigned j = 10; 
std::cout << i + j;
```

I get out `-5 % UINT_MAX`. Is this because the expression `i + j` is automatically promoted to an unsigned? I was trying to read the standard (4.13):

`— The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type.`

I'm not sure if I'm reading this incorrectly, but if that is true, why is `i + j` ending up as unsigned?

**b)** Adding onto the previous segment, I now have:

```
int k = j + i;
```

That is getting evaluated to `-5`. Shouldn't the expression `j + i` be evaluated first, giving `4294967291` on my system, and setting that equal to j? That should be out of bounds, so is this behavior undefined? I'm not sure why I get `-5`.

**c)** If I change the segment from *a)* slightly using `short`, I have:

```
short i = -15;
unsigned short j = 10;
std::cout << i + j;
```

I figured when I did this, I would get the same result as *a)*, just with `-5 % USHRT_MAX`. However, when I execute this, I get `-5`. Why does using `short` give a different value than `int`?

**d)** I have always learned that the overflow behavior of a signed integral is undefined. For example: `int r = ++INT_MAX` would be undefined.

However, if there was an unsigned overflow, the quantity would be defined. For example: `unsigned a = ++UINT_MAX`, then a would be `0`. Is that correct?

However, the standard didn't seem to say anything about it. Is that true? If so, why is that?

Comment: @ildjarn Thank you for the response. If I understand your post in the other thread, in **a)**, the `+` operator returns an unsigned value, which explains the response. However in **b)**, there a implementation specific change that makes it `-5`?

Comment: **b)** is equivalent to `int k = static_cast<int>(j + static_cast<unsigned>(i));`. The behavior of `static_cast<unsigned>(i)` is described in the standard thusly (§4.7/2): "*If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).*" The behavior of `static_cast<int>(j + static_cast<unsigned>(i))` is implementation-defined in this case because `4294967291` is too large to be represented with an `int` (§4.7/3 as quoted in my answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) From §5/9:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which are defined as follows:
>
> - If either operand is of type `long double`, the other shall be
>     converted to `long double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other shall be converted to `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `float`, the other shall be converted to `float`.
> - Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands.
> - Then, if either operand is `unsigned long` the other shall be   converted to `unsigned long`.
> - Otherwise, if one operand is a `long int` and the other `unsigned int`, then if a `long int` can represent all the values of an `unsigned int`, the `unsigned int` shall be converted to a `long int`; otherwise both operands shall be converted to `unsigned long int`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `long`, the other shall be converted to `long`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `unsigned`, the other shall be converted to `unsigned`.
>
> [*Note:* otherwise, the only remaining case is that both operands are `int`]

Therefore, since `j` is `unsigned`, `i` is promoted to `unsigned` and the addition is performed using unsigned int arithmetic.

b) This is UB. The result of the addition is `unsigned int` (as per (a)), and thus you overflow the `int` in the assignment.

c) From §4.5/1:

> An rvalue of type `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `short int`, or `unsigned short int` can be converted to an rvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source rvalue can be converted to an rvalue of type `unsigned int`.

Therefore, since a 4-byte `int` can represent any value in a 2-byte `short` or `unsigned short`, both are promoted to `int` (per §5.9's integral promotions rule), and then added as `int`s.

d) From §3.9.1/4:

> Unsigned integers, declared `unsigned`, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup> where *n* is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.

Therefore, `UINT_MAX+1` is legal (not UB) and equal to 0.

Comment: b) is implementation-defined behavior, not undefined behavior (§4.7/3).