# Integer promotion, signed/unsigned, and printf

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, integer-promotion

I was looking through [C++ Integer Overflow and Promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889237/c-integer-overflow-and-promotion), tried to replicate it, and finally ended up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = -15;
    unsigned int j = 10; 
    cout << i+j << endl; // 4294967291
    printf("%d\n", i+j); // -5 (!)
    printf("%u\n", i+j); // 4294967291

    return 0;
}
```

The `cout` does what I expected after reading the post mentioned above, as does the second `printf`: both print 4294967291. The first `printf`, however, prints -5. Now, my guess is that this is `printf` simply interpreting the unsigned value of 4294967291 as a signed value, ending up with -5 (which would fit seeing that the 2's complement of 4294967291 is 11...11011), but I'm not 100% convinced that I did not overlook anything. So, am I right or is something else happening here?

Comment: This is simply UB. Passing the wrong type to `printf` invokes UB.

Comment: @R..: Yes, I figured that, but I wanted to make sure that I was not missing something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you got it right. That's why `printf()` is generally unsafe: it interprets its arguments strictly according to the format string, ignoring their actual type.