# compare integers with different signedness

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote some program to test my suspicions. It contains super-ultra-reliable function, on my mind `:)`, called `less` to compare integral numbers. For some combinations of types it produces results that differ from the results, which gives **C++**. When this happens it gives false, that you can see on the screen.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <type_traits> 
#include <limits> 
#include <typeinfo> 

#include <cstdlib> 

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-compare" 
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtype-limits" 
template< typename T, typename U > 
inline 
bool less(T const & lhs, U const & rhs) 
{ 
    if (std::is_signed< T >::value && std::is_unsigned< U >::value) { 
        if (lhs < 0) { 
            return true; 
        } else if (rhs > std::numeric_limits< T >::max()) { 
            return true; 
        } else { 
            return static_cast< T >(lhs) < rhs; 
        } 
    } else if (std::is_unsigned< T >::value && std::is_signed< U >::value) { 
        if (rhs < 0) { 
            return false; 
        } else if (lhs > std::numeric_limits< T >::max()) { 
            return false; 
        } else { 
            return lhs < static_cast< T >(rhs); 
        } 
    } else { 
        return lhs < rhs; 
    } 
} 
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wtype-limits" 
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wsign-compare" 

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-compare" 
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtype-limits" 
template< typename U, typename S > 
void test() 
{ 
    std::cout << typeid(U).name() << " vs " << typeid(S).name() << std::endl; 
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned< U >::value && std::is_signed< S >::value, "signedness violated"); 
    static_assert(sizeof(U) != sizeof(S), "size should not be the same"); 
    U const x(std::numeric_limits< U >::max() - 2); 
    S const y(-1); 
    S const z(std::numeric_limits< S >::min()); 
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (less(x, y) == (x < y)) << std::endl 
              << std::boolalpha << (less(y, x) == (y < x)) << std::endl 
              << std::boolalpha << (less(y, z) == (y < z)) << std::endl 
              << std::boolalpha << (less(z, y) == (z < y)) << std::endl 
              << std::boolalpha << (less(x, z) == (x < z)) << std::endl 
              << std::boolalpha << (less(z, x) == (z < x)) << std::endl 
              << std::endl; 
} 
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wtype-limits" 
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wsign-compare" 

int main() 
{ 
    using namespace std; 

    test< uint8_t,  int16_t >(); 
    test< uint8_t,  int32_t >(); 
    test< uint8_t,  int64_t >(); 
    test< uint16_t, int8_t  >(); 
    test< uint16_t, int32_t >(); 
    test< uint16_t, int64_t >(); 
    test< uint32_t, int8_t  >(); 
    test< uint32_t, int16_t >(); 
    test< uint32_t, int64_t >(); 
    test< uint64_t, int8_t  >(); 
    test< uint64_t, int16_t >(); 
    test< uint64_t, int32_t >(); 

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

I compile (`bash s.sh 2>&1 | tee s.log`) the program using the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh 

set -o errexit 
set -o verbose 

g++ -std=gnu++11 -m64 s.cpp -o s64 
g++ -std=gnu++11 -m32 s.cpp -o s32 

MINGWDIR=/c/mingw64
PATH=/usr/bin:${MINGWDIR}/bin:/c/Windows/system32:${MINGWDIR}/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32 ./s64 2>&1 | tee s64.log | grep -c false
PATH=/usr/bin:${MINGWDIR}/bin:/c/Windows/system32:${MINGWDIR}/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32 ./s32 2>&1 | tee s32.log | grep -c false

diff s32.log s64.log
```

As a result (`s.log`) script gives the following:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -m64 s.cpp -o s64 
g++ -std=gnu++11 -m32 s.cpp -o s32 

MINGWDIR=/c/mingw64
PATH=/usr/bin:${MINGWDIR}/bin:/c/Windows/system32:${MINGWDIR}/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32 ./s64 2>&1 | tee s64.log | grep -c false
10
PATH=/usr/bin:${MINGWDIR}/bin:/c/Windows/system32:${MINGWDIR}/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32 ./s32 2>&1 | tee s32.log | grep -c false
10

diff s32.log s64.log
```

As you can see the results are the same (for **x32** and **x64** platforms). And some of the tests have failed. Why is this happening? My program is wrong or my knowledge about **C++** is little?

Comment: Are you asking why the results are the same, or why some tests have failed?

Comment: Why some tests have failed?

Answer (score 2):

You are testing whether the fundamental `operator <` functions the same as your `less` function.  It does not.

Your function accounts for signed/unsigned mismatch and gives the mathematically correct answer.

The fundamental C++ operator will convert the signed value to an unsigned value when there's a signed/unsigned mismatch.

Comment: It does this by performing type expansion?

Comment: There are plenty of existing questions on how integral conversion works in C++.

Comment: It will interpret the bits of the signed value as if it were unsigned.  That's why you were getting warnings.  The warnings are telling you *"This is fast, but it might not be what you want"*

Comment: @Dukales : See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6770275/636019) for the standardese.