# C++11 type of (signed + unsigned)?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int s = 2;
    unsigned int u = 3;

    auto k = s + u;

    if (typeid(k) == typeid(s))
        cout << "signed" << endl;
    else if (typeid(k) == typeid(u))
        cout << "unsigned" << endl;
    else
        cout << "error" << endl;
}
```

The output of this program by GCC is:

```
unsigned
```

I'm pretty sure this is either undefined or implementation-defined behaviour - but I can't seem to connect the dots with the standard.

Can you tell me where in the standard it says this?

Comment: Yes, this is standard behavior. unsigned types are "larger" than signed types of the same size.

Comment: Why do you say it's undefined or implementation defined, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: When operating on `signed` and `unsigned`, `unsigned` wins. I had some serious trouble once arising out of this fact... Lesson learnt for life.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's relevant but it says in the standard "The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type", so how do you conclude that "unsigned wins" from the standard?

Comment: I am surprised about that: assumed int s = - 4; and unsigned int u = 3; -  so what? How can -1 be unsigned?

Comment: @duDE the -4 gets converted to an unsigned value (UINT_MAX - 3) and then is added to 3.

Comment: @teppic: Thanks, I see! But that is nevertheless not the result I would expected on the first glance - that is what I meant.

Comment: @duDE: FYI `-1 < 1U` is `false`

Comment: @user1131467: You mean surely that because of unsigned int on the right the signed int on the left will be converted to unsigned as well and will be UINT_MAX than?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do promotion rules work when the signedness on either side of a binary operator differ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770258/how-do-promotion-rules-work-when-the-signedness-on-either-side-of-a-binary-opera)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're seeing are just the effects of the [Usual Arithmetic Conversions](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-7-of-n).

The standard says the following:

`§5 [expr] p7`:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions, which are defined as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands. Then the following rules shall be applied to the promoted operands:
>
>   - [...]
>   - Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.