# If statement checking NSArray size

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I've an if statement, used to check if an indice is less than the end of the array.
This is not working when the value of "i" is -1.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[myArray addObject:@"coucou"];

int i = -1;

// Not working
if (i < ([myArray count] - 1) ){
    NSLog(@" first ok ");
}

// Fix
int count = [myArray count] - 1;
if ( i < count ){
    NSLog(@" second ok ");
}
```

This is what i need to do to get it working (same algorithm, but using an intermediate variable to store the size of the array)
Anyone know why ?

Comment: because [myArray count] returns NSUInteger and you are compairing it with int variable. 

use (int)[myArray count]. It will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[myArray count]` return a NSUInteger which is an unsigned integer value.

When you compare an unsigned integer with an signed integer, the signed integer will be convert to unsigned, so the value `i` is not negative now.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770258/how-do-promotion-rules-work-when-the-signedness-on-either-side-of-a-binary-opera) for more information.

Comment: Yeah much closer to the truth.  You should emphasize that by "not negative" you actually get "very large" during such conversions.

Comment: Unsigned value is the 2's complement of the signed value. That's why for negative values it results in very large/small number like this: (2^32 - abs(your number)). The number of bits are machine architecture dependent. If your integer carries 4 byte then its 32 bit etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a signed integer with int thats why it is happening use NSUInteger instead of int.
It will definitely work

Comment: because when you are writing `if (i < ([myArray count] - 1) ){
    NSLog(@" first ok ");
} `([myArray count] - 1) gives you and unsigned integer and you are comparing it with int use expression [myArray count]-1 to debug you will get your answer

Answer (score 0):

`[myArray count]` it returns unsigned long value you need to keep either of these two

```
((NSInteger)[myArray count] - 1) OR ((int)[myArray count] - 1)
```