# Incorrectly signed addition when using function pointer

Tags: c

Using `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, the following program gives a different output depending on compiler optimisation level:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned short p = 100;

void f(signed char o) {
    // o is signed, so 0xfc should be interpreted as -4 here, but it is not always
    p += o;
}

int main(void) {
    void (*fp)(unsigned char o);
    fp = (void (*)(unsigned char))f;

    printf("%d\n", p);

    fp(0xfc);

    printf("%d\n", p);

    return 0;
}
```

Output with `-O0` (desired):
    100
    96

Output with `-O2` (undesired):
    100
    352

I wish for the program to output `96`, when using `-O2`.

Using `-fwrapv`, or `-fno-strict-overflow` has no affect.

I cannot change the type of `fp`, I want `f` to always interpret the first parameter as a `signed char` (so it sees 0xfc as -4).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do promotion rules work when the signedness on either side of a binary operator differ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770258/how-do-promotion-rules-work-when-the-signedness-on-either-side-of-a-binary-opera)

Comment: You need to provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you should post actual, compiling code,  even the two lines posted have an error as the second line is referencing 'o' and not 'p'

Comment: that's not an error, that's the output.

Comment: @imallett that's a C++ thread, and doesn't seem to explain OP's issue anyway

Comment: The `printf` is erroneous and irrelevant.  Post the complete code of the function with the actual value of `p` and the observed behaviour. What do you get with `-O0` and what with `-O2`.

Comment: I have posted a more complete sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a function through a pointer of different type is **undefined behavior**.

There are no guarantees.  The compiler is doing the "right" thing, because anything is allowed.

You said you cannot change the type of `fp`, therefore the fix is to change the type of `f`:

```
void f(unsigned char uo)
{
    signed char o = (signed char)uo; // value is implementation-defined :(
    p += o;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem here is unsigned promotion.  Due to a somewhat surprising behavior in C, binary operators on an unsigned value and a signed value will promote the signed value to be unsigned before the operation.

Yes.  It's weird.  Try this program to confirm ([live demo](http://ideone.com/T9hmGE)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { printf("%d",(int)( -1 < 0u )); return 0; }
```

`-1` is surely less than `0`, and yet this program outputs false.  What happened is that `-1` got promoted to an unsigned value before the comparison (since, unlike `0`, `0u` is unsigned).  Since no unsigned number can be less than unsigned zero, the comparison then evaluates to false.

I very strongly suspect this is what's happening in your example:

```
signed char o = -4;
unsigned short p = /*...*/;
p += o;
```

Because `p` is unsigned, `o` gets converted to an unsigned char: the bit pattern of `-4` in two's complement is `0xFC`, which is `252` if interpreted as unsigned.

Since you now have two unsigned operands, the addition can now proceed, and `252` is added onto `p`.

---

As far as what to *do* about it?  Well, you could make `p` a signed variable so that this doesn't happen.  You could subtract a positive value instead of adding a negative one.  It's hard to know without seeing your use case.

Comment: this answer is wrong, unfortunately. `o` never gets converted to an `unsigned char`. The integral promotions are the first thing that happen. On a system where `sizeof(short) < sizeof(int)`, then both `o` and `p` are promoted to signed `int`.   On other systems the calculation is done as `unsigned short` (or `unsigned int` in the rare case of sizeof(int)==1), however the result will still appear as I described in my answer; e.g. `(unsigned short)7 + (unsigned short)-4` gives `(unsigned short)3`.

Comment: Possibly he is using plain `char` and assumes it is signed when in fact it is unsigned, although it's really impossible to say until he posts his code.

Comment: slight correction, the second case after usual arithmetic conversion is `(unsigned int)p + (unsigned int)(int)o`, but same result