# Signed vs Unsigned comparison

Tags: c++, compare, unsigned, signed

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    signed int a = 5;
    unsigned char b = -5;
    unsigned int c = a > b;

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

This code prints `0`.

Can anyone please explain what is happening here? I am guessing that compiler converts `a` and `b` to same type(`unsigend int` maybe) and compares them.

Comment: You might want to read about [integral conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_conversions).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do promotion rules work when the signedness on either side of a binary operator differ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770258/how-do-promotion-rules-work-when-the-signedness-on-either-side-of-a-binary-opera)

Comment: You may find an answer here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175253/why-does-an-unsigned-int-compared-with-a-signed-character-turn-out-with-an-unexp

Comment: You can imagine `unsigned char b = -5` as first declare an `int` -5, and then assign it to `unsigned char`. The assignment just use the lower bits if -5, so it `b` will be 251

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see how the computer stores the value b:
`5` is `00000101`, so `-5` will be `11111011`, so, when you convert it to `unsigned char`, it will became some positive number with value `11111011` in binary, which is larger than `00000101`.
So, that's why `a = 00000101` is smaller than `b` (0 means false).

Comment: Please cite the standard sources that prescribe this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

It is printing `0` because `a < b` and `0` means false.  The type of `b` is `unsigned` so it cannot hold negative numbers.  Because of that `-5` becomes `251` which is grater than `5`.

Answer (score 2):

Lets go to the third line in `main`
`c` take the value of `0` because `a` is not greater than `b`. This is because in C zero is considered false and everything then else is true.

With regards to `b`. Most platforms store negative integers using 2s complement format. So when we negate an number we flip all the bits and add 1. So -5 unsigned become 0xfa which is greater than 5.