# uint8_t operations, when do they overflow?

Tags: c++, char, overflow, unsigned-char, integer-promotion

I'm not sure when I have to worry about overflows when using unsigned chars. This case is clear:

```
uint8_t a = 3;
uint8_t b = 6;
uint8_t c = a - b; // c is 253
```

However, what happens here:

```
float d = a - b; // d is -3
```

Are both a and be converted to float before doing the subtraction?

Or also in this case:

```
float e = (a - b) + (a - c);
```

Are all three variables converted to float?

Are there possible cases where an overflow can occur, even when the variable being assigned to is a float? Are the rules the same if *e* is a float, or int, or anything else?

Also, what happens in a case like this:

```
int a = std::abs(a - b);
```

Comment: unsigned operations never overflow, they just wrap around. `uint8_t c = a - b;` means `uint8_t c = (uint8_t)((int)a - (int)b);` which produces the wrapped result after the cast

Comment: TO add to @LưuVĩnhPhúc's comment, overflow is bad, very bad. It is undefined behavior. Unsigned integers never overflow. They instead use modulo 2^n arithmetic.

Comment: Also see [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/1708801)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your case is not a result of char-to-float conversions, but is due to the integer promotion rules.
[Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) states the following (emphasis mine):

> Prvalues of small integral types (such as char) may be converted to prvalues of larger integral types (such as int). In particular, **arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as arguments**, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable. This conversion always preserves the value.

And:

> unsigned char or unsigned short can be converted to int if it can hold its entire value range, and unsigned int otherwise.

So in your case, the `-` operator converts the values to integers, which are then converted to floats. Only the assignment to `c` converts back to a `uint8_t` (which overflows).

The same applies to the `std::abs` example: The values are converted before the subtraction, and the result in passed to the functions.

For more details on signed/unsigned promotions on arithmetic operations, see for example this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770275/3198247