# C++11 auto type deduction from arithmetic operation on int& and long

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, c++14, auto

I must be misunderstanding how `auto` c++11 and later resolves types.  I have the following code:

```
void foo(int& x)
{
    ++x;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    int& ir = i;
    long L = 5;
    auto a = ir/L;
    foo(a);

    return 0;
}
```

This results in the compiler error:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':

test.cpp:12:10: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference
of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’
     foo(a);
          ^

test.cpp:1:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void foo(int&)’
 void foo(int& x)
      ^~~
```

However, replacing `auto` with `int` (`int a = ir/L;`) compiles fine and gives the expected result (`a == 0` before the call to `foo()`, and `a == 1` after). After playing around with the code and seeing various error messages, I think `auto` is deduced to `long int&`. Defining the functions `void bar(int x)` and `void bar(const int& x)` results in the error message: `call of overloaded ‘bar(long int&)’ is ambiguous`.

**Correction from comments:**

I don't understand how `auto x = [int&]/[int]` result in an lvalue that can be passed by non-const ref while `auto x = [int&]/[long]` results in an rvalue that cannot.

Comment: `a` is not a reference, it's a simple `long`.

Comment: ^^^^^^ [Yup, it's just `long`](http://ideone.com/lGpcWt)

Comment: If you don't understand why it's long, the reason is type promotion. And you should [read the answer to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770258/how-do-promotion-rules-work-when-the-signedness-on-either-side-of-a-binary-opera)

Comment: I have to agree that the error message is misleading if not wrong. It should read `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘long’`. VS2015's error message is more helpful: `'void foo(int &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'long' to 'int &'`

Comment: @LogicStuff Updated question, it wasn't the type, but the rvalue error that confused me.

Comment: @StoryTeller I corrected the question: I meant the rvalue part of the error.

Comment: The error makes perfect sense when you consider `x` is long. To pass it to a function expecting an `int` (or `int&`), a temporary (rvalue) `int` is created. And it cannot bind to non-const reference.

Comment: @StoryTeller I know where the message comes from yet I still find it unfortunate. It would be better if the compiler had used the type before the implicit cast to explain what does not work...just saw that my proposal was wrong as I wrote `rvalue of type ‘long’` which should have been `lvalue of type ‘long’`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `ir/L` is `long`. For [arithmetic operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions), when binary operators have different types, the result produced will be of the common type; between `int` and `long` it would be `long`.

So `auto a = ir/L;`, the type of `a` is `long`. It can't be passed to `foo(int&)` because you can't bind lvalue reference to non-const with different type.

On the other hand, given the type of `L` is `int`, then for `auto a = ir/L;`, the type of `a` will be `int`, then everything is fine.

About the "the rvalue part of the error", when you pass a `long` to `foo(int&)`, firstly the compiler will try to convert it to `int`, which is a temporary (i.e. an rvalue) and can't be bound to lvalue reference to non-const.

`long` could be implicitly converted to `int`, and temporary could be bound to lvalue reference to const, so passing a `long` variable to both `bar(int x)` and `bar(const int&)` is fine.

BTW: When you write `int a = ir/L;`, the result of type `long` is implicitly converted to `int`. So you'll get an `int` then it's fine to pass it to `foo(int&)`.

Comment: I see. I never considered the type conversion creating a temporary value (the rvalue in the error message). This makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you've used `auto` is not relevant.

`a` is a `long` type, due to the rules of argument promotion.

Because `foo` takes the parameter *by reference*, compilation fails since an `int&` cannot bind to a `long` type (even if they are the same size and have the same complement representation).

Comment: `int const&` would bind to the temporary narrowed `int` quite well.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Absolutely!