# How is the type of auto determined when multiplying a value by a static_cast<uint8_t>

Tags: c++

For this code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto a =     static_cast<uint8_t>(sizeof(uint64_t));
    auto b = 8 * static_cast<uint8_t>(sizeof(uint64_t));

    auto c =     static_cast<uint32_t>(sizeof(uint64_t));
    auto d = 8 * static_cast<uint32_t>(sizeof(uint64_t));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

- The type of `a` resolves to `unsigned char`,
- The type of `b` resolves to `int`,
- The type of `c` resolves to `unsigned int` and,
- The type of `d` resolves to `unsigned int`

I expect these results for `a`, `c`, and `d`, but I'm baffled by `b`.

64 clearly fits in a 8-bit `unsigned char`. Can anyone explain, please?

[image: casting to auto]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5563000/1896169 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/6770258/1896169

Comment: It does not hurt to read the documentation.

Comment: @Phil1970 What documentation? The C++ documentation? You mean the standard? I got a great answer in 3 minutes (literally). I can't image how long it would have taken me to look it up in the standard.

Comment: @BlairFonville You could even be much faster that that by using **Google**. In less than 10 seconds, you can find that page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion.

Comment: @Phil1970 Yes, if I had already known the answer I could have found it on Google almost immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not "casting to auto" (which would be meaningless/impossible); auto, as it always does, is triggering the compiler to take the type of the expression on the RHS. That type is governed not by runtime values and how many bits you have, but by the standard. And the standard's integer promotion rules mean that the result of a multiplication is an `int` type, not `char`. No integer promotion is required when the expression is *already* an `int` type, though, so `d` keeps the `unsigned`ness of its right-hand operand.

Comment: It might be worth a mention that `uint8_t` and its ilk is displayed differently in the debugger.